# Isn't "document.body.firstChild.nodeName" = tagName of first element of body?

Tags: javascript, html

The alertbox displays '#text'. It should say 'h1' by my understanding. What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="bodi">

<h1 id="id01">My First Page</h1>

<script>
alert(document.body.firstChild.nodeName);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are thinking of [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild), [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) is the first node, ie your text node

Comment: `firstChild` would be a text node (with two newlines) that appears before `h1`.

Comment: @trincot. you are right. that solves it. But i presumed that whitespace is not counted as child of node. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firstElementChild property returns only elements, while the firstChild property returns element, #text, #comment... So To return h1, you have to use firstElementChild property

```
<script>
  alert(document.body.firstElementChild.tagName);
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
  alert(document.getElementById("id01").tagName);
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer, but you should add a comment or explanation why he should use that solution =)

Comment: The firstElementChild property returns only elements, while the firstChild property returns element, #text, #comment... So To return h1, you have to use firstElementChild property